# More cttypes c_float() precision

Tags: python, floating-point, ctypes, floating-accuracy

I'm using Python's `ctypes` library to call my C code. My problem is that when I try to create a `c_float`, I seem to obtain a slightly different value to what I set.

For example

```
print(value)
print(c_float(value))

0.2
c_float(0.20000...298...)
```

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Floating point numbers are often only approximations of the numbers you're trying to represent. `c_float(0.2)` will never be *exactly* 0.2 - it will always have inaccuracy is the lower-order bits. (The Python float has similar error.)

Comment: Sorry, but that's just the way floating point numbers work. Floats are stored in binary, and 0.2 decimal == 1/5 = 3/15, so in binary that's 0.001100110011...See [Why Are Floating Point Numbers Inaccurate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate) for more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jan Rüegg is right - this is just how floats work.

If you're wondering why this only shows up with `c_float`, it's because

- `c_float`s print as `"c_float({!r}).format(self.value)`. `self.value` is a **double**-precision Python float.
- Python's `float` type prints the shortest representation that *converts to* the floating point number, so although `float(0.2)` is not exact it can still be printed in short form.

The inaccuracy in `c_float(0.2)` is high enough to make it closer to

```
0.20000000298023223876953125
```

than to

```
0.200000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125
```

Since `float(0.2)` represents the later, the short form of `"0.2"` cannot be used.

Answer (score 1):

Python's `float` corresponds to a C double, typically 64 bits wide. On the other hand a ctypes `c_float` corresponds to a C `float`, typically 32 bits wide. This is why you observe a degradation in accuracy - it is expected when representing a number inexactly with a narrower type.

c_float's `__repr__` adds to the confusion by converting the number back to a Python float in order to print it, so its output includes additional unnecessary digits. 32-bit floats can be printed using 9 significant digits, while 64-bit floats require 17. The extra digits carry no additional information and make it look like the number has been corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Floats have a fixed precision, and cannot necessarily represent finite numbers in decimal representation exactly.

On [this website](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) you can see how the float is actually stored in memory. If you enter "0.2" in "Decimal Representation", you can see how it is converted to a hex number, and that the stored number is exactly the number you noticed.